# sending and recieving two double with a message in Anylogic

Tags: message, anylogic

I want to send the message in an Anylogic model from each agent to others which the message has two parameters. when another agent received the message in the "communication", check the first parameter. if it passes a condition, we use a second parameter in a way and if not, we use it in another way.
for example:
 X, Y, and Z are the parameters of the agents.

I send a message in a transition.

and received it in "connection-link to agent"

I want to have this condition:

if sender.X > receiver.X
receiver.Z=receiver.Z + sender.Y;

if sender.X < receiver.X
receiver.Z=receiver.Z - sender.Y;

so I should send X and Y Simultaneously from an agent to another. 
but I can not send a message in a transition as:
sendToAllConnected(X,Y);

could you help me?

I use this code ( "op" is a agent parameter):

```
    if(msg.op<this.op)                                                                                                                  
    this.op=this.op+msg; 
    if (msg.op<this.op) 
    this.op=this.op-msg;
```

and this code:

```
    if (sender.op<this.op) 
    this.op=this.op+msg; 
    if (sender.op<this.op) 
    this.op=this.op-msg;
```

but I have an error that op cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a reference to the sender object.  Don't try to send the X and Y values.  Once you send the sender object, then the receiving object can reason with that message object (a reference to the sender) and get the applicable values of x and y.
[image]

Comment: I use from your solution but it has an error. in msg.X it says X can not be resolved  or is not a field

Comment: I edited the main question and added what I did in order to your answer.

Comment: what did you send for the message in transition?

Comment: I used sendToAllConnected( agent ).  The agent (sender) is the message.  You cannot say value minus msg, if msg is an object and not a value.  If "op" (or "x" in my example) is defined as a variable for your agent class, then it should be recognized by AnyLogic.  Make sure your message type matches your agent type.  Otherwise, you will need to pass in a generic object and reason with/do casting.

Comment: I used sendToAllConnected( agent ) too. but its error is agent cannot be resolved to a variable. I am tried my agent name but it did not work.

Comment: What is your agent name?  Did you put the class name or a reference to the agent (a variable)?  Would sentToAllConnected( this ) work?  This means the agent that is the class we are in (see Java documentation).

Comment: thanks a lot. I think sentToAllConnected( this ) works